Why is there no default password generated to the console in Spring Security 6?
I created following API endpoint secured by Spring Security 6.
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "index";
    }
}

Dependencies are shown below.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I haven't defined a SecurityConfig class or UserDetails object. I just want to use the default username user and default password generated by Spring Security. However, when I started the application, there is no default password generated. Is there any configuration needed?


As you didn't include application configuration properties, it's impossible to figure out what Boot auto-configures for your app. Also it seems that what you are looking for is not OAuth2: neither OAuth2 clients nor OAuth2 resource servers are concerned with user credentials.

Since Spring Boot 3.2.2 you have to configure name and password in your application.yaml, see Spring Boot 3.2 Release Notes:

Auto-configured User Details Service
The auto-configured InMemoryUserDetailsManager now backs off when one or more of spring-security-oauth2-client, spring-security-oauth2-resource-server, and spring-security-saml2-service-provider is on the classpath and, since 3.2.2, neither spring.security.user.name nor spring.security.user.password has been configured. Similarly, in reactive applications, the auto-configured MapReactiveUserDetailsService now backs off when one or more of spring-security-oauth2-client and spring-security-oauth2-resource-server is one the classpath and, since 3.2.2, neither spring.security.user.name nor spring.security.user.password has been configured.
If you are using one of the above dependencies yet still require an InMemoryUserDetailsManager or MapReactiveUserDetailsService in your application, define the required bean in your application, or with Spring Boot 3.2.2 and later, configure one or both of spring.security.user.name and spring.security.user.password.


Thanks for your reply. I know I can configure spring.security.user.name and spring.security.user.password in application.yml but I haven't realized that such configurations are needed since Spring Boot 3.2.2.
